# Why can the parameter `n` of function l`ua_upvalueindex` be 256?

Tags: lua, closures, upvalue

Hi~ I need some helps as i couldn't understand c closures in lua reference manual. As follows:

2)

> `void lua_pushcclosure (lua_State *L, lua_CFunction fn, int n);`
>   ...
>   The maximum value for `n` is 255.
>   ...

1)

> Any access to `lua_upvalueindex(n)`, where `n` is greater than the number of upvalues of the current function (but not greater than 256, which is one plus the maximum number of upvalues in a closure), produces an acceptable but invalid index.

Both 1) and 2) are descriptions in Lua reference manual. And I am puzzled:

Why can the argument `n` of `lua_upvalueindex` be 256 when the maximum number of upvalues is 255?

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Probably, number of upvalues must fit in a byte?  That's why `n` <= 255.  And index `256` might be reserved just in case you want to create acceptable but invalid index (such index would mean "no upvalue").